# Span element create large height on text resize

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div id>` with multiple `<div class>`'s, 3 to be exact. Each class has a `<span>` element inside of it. Like so;

```
<div id="section">
    <div class="phones"><span>Our Phones</span></div>
    <div class="contract"><span>Our Contracts</span></div>
    <div class="network"><span>Our Network</span></div>
</div>
```

Each style of the class looks like so;

```
.phones {
    background-image: url('../img/c_button_1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 230px;
    color: #fff;
}
.phones:hover {
    transform: 2s;
    background-image: url('../img/c_button_1_hover.png');
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Everything works as it should to this point. My problem is, I have a buttons to control the text size of the website, small, medium and large. Small and Medium correctly work, Large however causes the `<span>` elements to create a newline of the text with a significant height. Here's my jQuery code that changes the text size.

```
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#small").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("li").animate({"font-size":"16px"});
    $("h1").animate({"font-size":"16px"});
    $(".block").animate({"font-size":"16px", "line-height":"16px"});
    $("span").animate({"font-size":"10px"});

  });

  $("#medium").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("li").animate({"font-size":"22px"});
    $("h1").animate({"font-size":"22px"});
    $(".block").animate({"font-size":"22px", "line-height":"22px"});
    $("span").animate({"font-size":"18px"});

  });

  $("#large").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("li").animate({"font-size":"30px"});
    $("h1").animate({"font-size":"30px"});
    $(".block").animate({"font-size":"30px", "line-height":"30px"});
    $("span").animate({"font-size":"28px", "white-space":"nowrap"});
  });

  $( "a" ).click(function() {
   $("a").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).addClass("selected");

 });

});
</script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1n5csbkd/

Comment: could you provide any links to jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: can you please share live site link here...

Comment: Just creating the JSFiddle now.

Comment: Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1n5csbkd/

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS, where the line height is changed to 30px instead of 230px.

```
.phones {
    background-image: url('../img/c_button_1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
}
.phones:hover {
    transform: 2s;
    background-image: url('../img/c_button_1_hover.png');
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue. I have included a fiddle link to help with understanding my problem a bit more, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's happening because your font-size is too big to fit inside "phone div".
you set height: 100px and width: 100px to that div and when you choose the larger font, it doesnt know how to behave, so your layout gets broken.

What i would do is: put the text outside that phone div, so you can manage it better.

like this:

```
<div class="mainDivPhone">
   <div class="phone">
   </div>
   <div class="phoneLegend">
      <span>your text</span>
   </div>
</div>
```